# Create arrowed background with CSS using repeating-gradient and blend-mode

Tags: css

I thought about creating a background with arrows. Something that looks like in this codepen:    http://codepen.io/DaSch/pen/rrWAmy

```
.top {
  height: 5em;
  background:
  repeating-linear-gradient(
     45deg,
     lightgray,
     lightgray 25%,
     gray 0,
     gray 50%
  );
  background-size: 5em 5em;
}
.bottom {
  height: 5em;
  background:
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    lightgray,
    lightgray 25%,
    gray 0,
    gray 50%
  );
  background-size: 5em 5em;
}
```

In the given example there are two elements but together to make it look like I want it to. If I but the gradients together I just get strips. I tried a lot but I can't figure out how to create arrows. with multiple gradients an background-blend-mode.

I'm not sure if this is possible. But I'm looking for a solution without external background-images. If it's not possible a good explanation why would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have. It looks like an arrow, and can be repeated using JavaScript. I can't do this with pure CSS. Maybe this solution gives you an idea for your code.

```css
.top {
  height: 5em;
  width:80px;
  margin-left:120px;
  background:
  repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  white,
  white 25%,
  gray 0,
  gray 50%
 );
  background-size: 5em 5em;
}
.bottom {
  height: 5em;
  width:80px;
  margin-left:120px;
  background:
  repeating-linear-gradient(
  135deg,
  white,
  white 25%,
  gray 0,
  gray 50%
 );
  background-size: 5em 5em;
}

.middle
{
  background-color:gray;
  height:30px;
  width:200px;
  margin-right:10px;
  
}

.maskCornerTop
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:white;
  float:right;
}

.maskCornerBottom
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:white;
  float:right;
  margin-top:40px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"><div class="maskCornerTop"></div></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="bottom"><div class="maskCornerBottom"></div></div>
<br/>
<div class="combo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found, that the solution is to overlay different backgrounds and use only the half hight for the upper one.
It'll look like this

```
.combo {
  height: 10em;
  background:
  repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      lightgray,
      lightgray 33.33%,
      gray 33.33%,
      gray 66.66%
  ),
  repeating-linear-gradient(
      135deg,
      gray,
      gray 25%,
      lightgray 25%,
      lightgray 50%
  );
  background-size: 10em 50%, 10em 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
}
```

Still this maybe isn't the best solution as it only works if the height of the container is known and fixed.